# Max users in XMPP roster?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Assume there is a bot who relays presence information of any user on the system to any other user on the system.

For this to work- it seems every user must be added to that bot's roster, correct?

Is this a problem- i.e. is there a limit to the max number of user's per roster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to do that. This is not a scalable design. Having a roster for the bot with all presence of the server is the best way to create a deadly bottleneck as you scale.

Consider writing a native ejabberd module that intercept the packet you want and does the needed processing.

Comment: Will a native ejabberd module get presence notifications without needing to create and maintain a roster? I only really need it while the server is online... if it goes down, the presence info does *not* need to be rebuilt (in fact it shouldn't- as the next step will be sending the presence info downstream, and I do not want it to flood upon restart, similar to the problem that would happen with a bot)

Comment: A native ejabberd plugin module can do everything on the server, yes, including intercepting presence packets (or reading the online state of user in memory).

Comment: Thanks Mickael! Is there a good example module for sending HTTP posts elsewhere upon presence notifications? Don't want that to be a bottleneck either (I'm not familiar with erlang yet- i.e. I'd think it should use a separate thread somehow so it doesn't block?)